# Jade multiline Object / Array

Tags: html, pug

I need to know how to split into lines objects / arrays in jade.

This works fine:

```
object = [{foo: bar, bar:foo},{foo: bar, bar:foo},{foo: bar, bar:foo}]
```

This doesn't:

```
object = [
   {foo: bar, bar:foo},
   {foo: bar, bar:foo},
   {foo: bar, bar:foo}
]
```

This doesn't either:

```
- object = [
-       {foo: bar, bar:foo},
-       {foo: bar, bar:foo},
-       {foo: bar, bar:foo}
- ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on [pug site](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code) says that this should work *(keep track of the white spaces)* :

```
-
  var object = [
    {foo: bar, bar:foo},
    {foo: bar, bar:foo},
    {foo: bar, bar:foo}
  ]
```